# mobx decorators don't work with Typescript

Tags: typescript, decorator, mobx, mobx-react

I just started developing a new project where i use mobx for a shared state management core module between a react web app and react-native mobile app.

The core module uses typescript, it is compiled and consumed by both app projects.

My problem is non of the components in both projects re-render when an `@observable` property in a store (from the core module) changes.

When I create a the store with the same definition and logic in each of the projects, the components re-render as expected. I've also transformed part of core module to javascript ES6 transpiled with babel-cli and it also works as expected.

I believe this issue has something with importing stores compiled from Typescript into a non typescript project, but i can't get over it!

Additional info:

The  `.ts` store file:

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx'

export class UserStore {
    @observable loading = false;

    @action login() {
        this.loading = true;
        setTimeout(() => {this.loading = false},1000)
    }
}
export const userStore = new UserStore();
```

The `.tsconfig` file:

```
{"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2015"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": ["index.ts", "src" ]}
```

Typescript version: 2.4.1

All projects use latest `mobx` and `mobx-react` versions.

Both react and react-native project use regular babel.

The component consuming the store (I've got a `Provider` configured..):

```
@inject('userStore')
@observer
class Loading extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.userStore.login();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        this.props.userStore.loading ? <div>loading...</div> : <div>loaded...</div>
) }}
```

Comment: You could try to use `mobx.useStrict` to make sure that you don't re-write the observable value to a simple value when you set it to a new value.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you solve it?

Comment: @BrickYang See the solution that worked for me in this issue: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1071